# possible to fetch @mentions thru Facebook API (like thru Twitter API?)

Tags: facebook

I'm looking to implement a feature where I am able to collect @mentions through the facebook API in a similar fashion to the twitter API.

Specifically, if I run a group called foo, and other people on facebook mention @foo in their wall posts, I'd like to fetch and collect the text of that particular @foo mention.

I can't find any relevant documentation on Facebook....

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant do this, the privacy policy on Facebook is much tougher than Twitter. Even application which being installed need to explicitly ask for  permission to read wall posts. if your application has read_stream permission from user then you can read his/her wall posts with API, and you can search for your group name there.